# QuTip - Is there a way to simulate more than one inital state in one simulation?

Tags: programming, simulation, qutip

I'm trying to use QuTip for a simulation of a qutrit system and I want to see how my system evolves under different initial states. Is there a way to do it using QuTip without running the simulation for each initial state separately?
For example, I want to run a simulation for $|0\rangle$ state and $|1\rangle$ **in the same run**, but in mesolve method in QuTip one can insert only one initial state if I understand correctly.